# $25$ cards with only $3$ possible pat hands

Tags: recreational-mathematics, card-games

In the game called Maverick Poker, $25$ cards are dealt and you try to make as many pat hands (hands which are a straight or better) as you possibly can.

If the cards are randomly dealt, the probability is extremely high that five pat hands can be made. However, I have it on good faith that it is possible to choose $25$ cards which can be partitioned into at most $3$ pat hands. I am not in contact with the person who told me this was true anymore, so I can't just ask for a solution (so instead I'm asking here!) -- anyone have any insight into how to choose these cards to make this possible?

Comment: Flush is higher than straight, and if you have at least $6$ cards from one suit, then you have at least $6$ flushes from this sut, so I do not think that this is possible. Actually you must have at least $7$ from some suit which gives $\dbinom{7}{5}=21$ flushes only from this suit.

Comment: @JimmyR I am pretty sure the five hands have to be using distinct cards. So you partition the 25 cards into 5 sets of 5 cards, each which is a straight or better.

Comment: @6005 Thank you for the clarification.